# ReactJS uncaught reference error worker is not defined

Tags: reactjs, mediarecorder

I'm having some issues:

`Uncaught reference error worker is not defined`

I'm implementing one code to `record audio`, this's my code:

```
//file records.tsx

import { ReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";
import React  from "react";

export default function RecordView(){
    return(
        <div> 
            <ReactMediaRecorder
                audio
                render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
                    <div>
                    <p>{status}</p>
                    <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
                    <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
                    <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay loop />
                    </div>
                )}
            /> 
      </div>
    )
};
```

so, I'm getting this issue:

[image]

Why I'm having this error???

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to reproduce the error, but my guess would be that it's related to HTTPS, seeing how [mediaDevices are only availible in HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mediaDevices).

This error is also mentioned in a [Github issue](https://github.com/0x006F/react-media-recorder/issues/107), with no response, and the project hasn't been updated since May 2022.

Try setting up your dev server to use HTTPS. If you're using Vite, you can use the [server.https option](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-https) with [vite-plugin-basic-ssl](https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-basic-ssl). There's probably a way to do this for webpack/CRA too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for hooks related to useReactMediaRecorder or class-based too:

Assume we have a custom component called CustomMediaRecorder that uses useReactMediaRecorder. We want to use this component in the current component.

```
 const CustomMediaRecorder = dynamic(
  () => import('..../CustomMediaRecorder'),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

NB. CustomMediaRecorder can be a class-based or functional component. Import it into your current component like the code snippet above shows.